# Node no longer exists error with session

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I am using session in a plugin of wordpress, and it gives me warning like below:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Node no longer exists in /----/---/plugins/----.php on line 11

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /----/---.php:11) in /---/---/---.php on line 11
```

On line 11, I have:

```
session_start();
```

There is no print out before session_start.
I have tried putting it just after the starting

```
<?php
```

But it did not fix this error.
For your information, I did not use any SimpleXMLElement here.
Any idea how to fix this, or why even I am getting this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any spaces are special chars before the <?php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realise you were referring to wordpress, you need to check a session id doesn't exist when you initalise your plugin,

```
function init_plugin() {
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'init_plugin');
```